# Python print in same line

Tags: python

I've been trying to write my output to the same line and have already searched Stackoverflow. It seems what works for everyone else is not working for me !! Here's my code:

```
count = float(len(emails))
counter = 0
symbols = ["/","-","|","\\","|"]
for e in emails:
    print '%s inserting emails %s%%\r' % (symbols[counter % 5], counter / count * 100),
    sys.stdout.flush()
    counter += 1
```

The comma after the print still causes a carriage return !!

```
| inserting emails 3.312%
\ inserting emails 3.313%
| inserting emails 3.314%
/ inserting emails 3.315%
- inserting emails 3.316%
| inserting emails 3.317%
\ inserting emails 3.318%
```

What is the issue?

Comment: What is your console? Not all consoles support this.

Comment: Your code works *in my Mac terminal*. If it doesn't work for you, then your console or terminal doesn't support printing to just the one line with a carriage return.

Comment: I believe on some consoles the \r must come at the start of the string, not the end

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm using PyDev in Eclipse

Comment: @QuinnFTW Nope. Already tested that.

Comment: @FarhadAlizadehNoori: Eclipse doesn't support this, no.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wow !!! Thanks Martijn. Coming from the world of .Net and Visual Studio, I'm baffled by this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance your console does not support this. You can test your functionality by using the other method of printing without a newline (using sys).

The way to do this is to use `sys.stdout.write('')` command. As an example:

```
import sys 
sys.stdout.write('hello %d' %(1))
```

your output will be

```
>>> sys.stdout.write('hello %d' %(1))
hello 1>>>
```

Comment: Well yes this works and so would the `print "xx",` but the problem is that I need to use '\r'.